# Accesing data from a List of objects results in property undefined

Tags: c#

Hi I have created a List of objects and when I try to acces the properties I get an error saying that the object does not contain a definition for that property.Here is my code:

This is is where I create the List of objects:

```
public List<object> returnProductData(SetProduct product)
    {
        List<object> productData = new List<object>();

        var type = product.GetType();
        var properties = type.GetProperties();

        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            if( propertyInfo.GetValue(product , null) != null && propertyInfo.Name != "ProductName" &&
                propertyInfo.Name != "Brand" && propertyInfo.Name != "ProductPrice" && propertyInfo.Name != "ProductImagePath" )
            {
                productData.Add(new { propertyName = propertyInfo.Name , propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(product , null).ToString()}) ;
            }
        }

        return productData;
    }
```

This is where I try to acces it:

```
@foreach( var productData in ion)
            {
                <li>@productData.propertyName</li>
            }
```

When I try to acces it it says that the object does not contain a definition for propertyName.What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `object` hasn't `propertyName` property.

If described scenario is very necessary and if you use .net 4.0 or above you can use `dynamic` like this:

```
public List<dynamic> returnProductData(SetProduct product)
    {
        List<dynamic> productData = new List<dynamic>();

        var type = product.GetType();
        var properties = type.GetProperties();

        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            if( propertyInfo.GetValue(product , null) != null && propertyInfo.Name != "ProductName" &&
                propertyInfo.Name != "Brand" && propertyInfo.Name != "ProductPrice" && propertyInfo.Name != "ProductImagePath" )
            {
                productData.Add(new { propertyName = propertyInfo.Name , propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(product , null).ToString()}) ;
            }
        }

        return productData;
    }
```

Usage:

```
@foreach( var productData in ion)
            {
                <li>@productData.propertyName</li>
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not return `List<object>` you should use a more specific type, e.g. `List<ProductData>`.

If that class doesn't exist then write it.